# Self referencing relationship in the fleet model

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

In the fleet management models, in the `fleet.vehicle.cost` model, we have these two fields:

```
 'parent_id': fields.many2one('fleet.vehicle.cost', 'Parent', help='Parent cost to this current cost'),
 'cost_ids': fields.one2many('fleet.vehicle.cost', 'parent_id', 'Included Services'),
```

Now, for the first one I understand its logic: a cost may have a parent cost. But I don't understand the second relation and how it works and why I don't find this field in the postgresql database.

Can you explain to me this please?

Comment: actually I dont know about the exact issue/solution but as per your last question why this relationship is not showing in postgresql reason is `One2many` fields aren't actually stored on the database table though. here you find some help https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-does-odoo-store-one2many-fields-84936

Comment: @AdamStrauss thank you for the answer, my question was more about the functional side, i want to understand the logic of the fleet management and why for example do we have this field cost_ids.

Answer (score 0):

1. Many2One: The system creates a field in a model/table in which a link to the associated model/table. In your example system create **parent_id** field into **fleet.vehicle.cost** model (Database table **fleet_vehicle_cost**).
2. One2Many: First need Many2one for setup One2many relationship. Because in the database there is no any special thing happen when we add One2Many field.

So, How it works:

When system try to get the records of One2many field then it will get basd on Many2one field.

For exmaple **sale_order** and **sale_order_line**

```
Model (sale.order.line)
order_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order')


Model (sale.order)
line_ids = fields.One2many('sale.order.line', 'order_id')
```

So, *For example we tried to open sales order it has id 7.
For getting data for sales order line system will get order_id field under sale_order_line model have value 7.*